# "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" in Twitter JSON data

Tags: python, json, postgresql, twitter

I am trying to insert some JSON files in PostgreSQL, but I am kind of new in it and I have some questions. So, I have the files already, which are encoded and here is a simple example of what I am trying to do. Creating some tables in Postgres and adding twitter information in it.

```
import json
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='bilabial' host='localhost'")
cur = conn.cursor()
linenumber = 0
data = open('tweets_testing.json').read()
for line in data:
    linenumber += 1
    try:
        str_line = line.strip()
        vals = json.loads(str_line)
        tweets = vals["text"]
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE tweetstext (text VARCHAR(255));")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweetstext (" + tweets+ ");")
        conn.commit()
    except KeyError:
        break
```

So the error I get is "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str". I don't understand very much the difference of it when I read about it, so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you share an example `str_line` ?

Comment: could you please post the full error?

Comment: File "SQLpy.py", line 18, in <module>
    tweets = vals["text"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: The line number is not 18, as I have written the code here. It is about the line saying "tweets=vals["text"]"

Comment: Also, you have an SQL injection vulnerability in your code. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks/2040#2040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vals = json.loads(str_line)
```

`type` of vals is **`list`**.
Check the type of `vals` by `print "Type vals", type(vals)`

**Demo :** According to your code.

```
>>> import json
>>> str_line = "[1,2,3,5]"
>>> vals = json.loads(str_line)
>>> vals
[1, 2, 3, 5]
>>> type(vals)
<type 'list'>
>>> vals["text"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>>>
```

---

Following line expecting `type` of `vals`should be `dict` i.e. dictionary.

```
`tweets = vals["text"]`
```

**Can you shear the value structure of `str_line` variable?**

---

**[Edit 2]**

According to me we need to loads all content of json file.

```
data = open('tweets_testing.json').read()
vals = json.loads(data)
```

but code will change according to Input and Logic.

Comment: So I get it, str_line is a string and vals becomes a list, whereas it should be a dictionary. But I don't understand how I make it. Should I split the words on my own?

Comment: can you shear sample input json file with us ?

Comment: [{
    "contributors": null, 
    "coordinates": null, 
    "created_at": "Fri Sep 25 12:43:12 +0000 2015", 
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "indices": [
                    128, 
                    139
                ], 
                "text": "vegetarian"
            }
        ], 
        "symbols": [], 
        "urls": [
 ......]

Comment: you got solution? We need to add `text` value to table. but from the given json I not able to get. Can you pass me json file vivekbsable@gmail.com ?

Comment: It doesn't allow me to post more than those characters. I will send it to you now!

Comment: `"text": "This pretty green side salad may add sparkle to your dinner party? Cucumber Hearts &amp; Candied Pecans https://t.co/fgdJXM4CHy #vegetarian"` This is tweet?